# Why my Array is empty after sent into function

Tags: arrays, powershell, arguments

I want to send several `parameters` into `function` and one of them is `array`.
Before call the `function` the array is with several items, when looking via the debugger inside the function the `array` is `empty\null`:

```
$arr = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList 
$arr.Add("test1")
GetProcessOutput -exeFile "c:\file.exe" -args $arr

function GetProcessOutput($exeFile, $args)
{
    # here my $args is empty -> children could not be evaluated
}
```

Comment: `$args` -> `${Something else that do not clash with $args automatic variable}`

Comment: You also should move  your function definition above your function call to improve script readability.

Answer (score 4):

`$args` is a [automatic variable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx), meaning that you are prevented from using the `args` name for a user-defined variable.

Use any other name and it'll work:

```
function GetProcessOutput([string]$exeFile,[array]$arguments)
{
    # $arguments will work just fine
}
```

---

From the [`about_Variables` help file](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847734.aspx):

> ```
>  There are several different types of variables in Windows
>  PowerShell.
>
> -- User-created variables: User-created variables are created and 
>    maintained by the user. By default, the variables that you create at
>    the Windows PowerShell command line exist only while the Windows 
>    PowerShell window is open, and they are lost when you close the window.
>    To save a variable, add it to your Windows PowerShell profile. You can 
>    also create variables in scripts with global, script, or local scope.    
>
> -- Automatic variables: Automatic variables store the state of 
>    Windows PowerShell. These variables are created by Windows PowerShell, 
>    and Windows PowerShell changes their values as required to maintain 
>    their accuracy. Users cannot change the value of these variables.
>    For example, the $PSHome variable stores the path to the Windows 
>    PowerShell installation directory.
> ```

Comment: Nicely done. Unfortunately, "prevented from using" with respect to `$args` means: "you're free to declare a parameter by this name, but it will be ignored", which is arguably a bug.
By contrast, trying to name a parameter `$PSHOME`, for instance, more sensibly results in error `Cannot overwrite variable PSHOME because it is read-only or constant.`